# Flutter: "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" when building child widget

Tags: flutter, timer, closures, setstate

I'm still kind of a newbie to both Flutter and StackOverflow, so I hope the question is clear and I didn't miss anything dumb.

I'm working on a small quiz app, where I have `ViewQuiz`, which is the page that displays the i-th card of the quiz. Each card is a Container that contains a question, 5 selectable answers (InkWell + Text), and other less relevant widgets. Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o1g7.png) picture to get a better idea.

**Problem: I get an exception when the app tries to build `ViewQuiz`, giving [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg3vv.png) error. In fact, each answer's InkWell is associated with `void _setUserAnswer(int)` function (which takes the answer index, and saves the current choice of the user using setState()).**

**More details** about the problem:

- The cause seems to be related to the function closure `(int index) => _setUserAnswer(index)` passed to the card widget, since it calls `setState()`, but I don't get why I cannot update the state of the parent `ViewQuiz`, from the child widget `QuestionWidget`;
- I've tried just printing something (instead of calling `_setUserAnswer()`, I tried to set `onTap` to `print("test")`) when the InkWell gets tapped, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI3FK.gif) is the result. As we can notice, the function gets called 5 times each time the timer ticks, which makes me think that there could also be a problem with the code of the timer;
- If I don't use an "external widget" and put everything inside the `ViewQuiz` class, obviously the problem doesn't occur and everything goes as expected. This is the solution I'm using right now, but it seems like cheating and I would rather fix the problem, making the code more readable, and understand exactly why it happens, than leaving it this way.

**Goal**: I want to set the state of the current selected answer from the child widget, through the function closure `(int index) => _setUserAnswer(index)`, which gets the index of the tapped answer element to know which one of the 5 answers has been tapped.

The project is available on GitHub ([flutter app](https://github.com/mikyll/ROQuiz/tree/main/app-mobile/flutter_application) and [latest release apk](https://github.com/mikyll/ROQuiz/releases/download/v1.5/roquiz-mobile.apk)), but here's the full code of the involved classes (which is a bit different from the one currently on the repository, since I edited it to make it work):

#### ViewQuiz class

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/model/Question.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/model/Answer.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/model/Quiz.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/model/Settings.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/model/Themes.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/widget/icon_button_widget.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/widget/question_widget.dart';

class ViewQuiz extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewQuiz({Key? key, required this.questions, required this.settings})
      : super(key: key);

  final List<Question> questions;
  final Settings settings;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ViewQuizState();
}

class _ViewQuizState extends State<ViewQuiz> {
  Quiz quiz = Quiz();

  bool _isOver = false;
  int _qIndex = 0;
  int _correctAnswers = 0;

  String _currentQuestion = "";
  List<String> _currentAnswers = [];

  List<Answer> _userAnswers = [];

  late Timer _timer;
  int _timerCounter = -1;

  int _dragDirectionDX = 0;

  void _previousQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (_qIndex > 0) _qIndex--;
    });
  }

  void _nextQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (_qIndex < widget.settings.questionNumber - 1) _qIndex++;
    });
  }

  void _loadQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _currentQuestion = quiz.questions[_qIndex].question;
      _currentAnswers = quiz.questions[_qIndex].answers;
    });
  }

  void _setUserAnswer(int answer) {
    setState(() {
      _userAnswers[_qIndex] = Answer.values[answer];
      if (Answer.values[answer] == quiz.questions[_qIndex].correctAnswer) {}
    });
  }

  void _endQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _isOver = true;
      _timer.cancel();
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.settings.questionNumber; i++) {
      if (_userAnswers[i] == quiz.questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        _correctAnswers++;
      }
    }
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_timerCounter > 0) {
          _timerCounter--;
        } else {
          _timer.cancel();
          _endQuiz();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void _resetQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _userAnswers = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < widget.settings.questionNumber; i++) {
        _userAnswers.add(Answer.NONE);
      }
      quiz.resetQuiz(widget.questions, widget.questions.length,
          widget.settings.shuffleAnswers);

      _qIndex = 0;
      _correctAnswers = 0;
      _isOver = false;
      _currentQuestion = quiz.questions[_qIndex].question;
      _currentAnswers = quiz.questions[_qIndex].answers;

      _timerCounter = widget.settings.timer * 60;
    });
    _startTimer();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    quiz.resetQuiz(widget.questions, widget.questions.length,
        widget.settings.shuffleAnswers);
    _resetQuiz();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        _endQuiz();
        return true;
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          setState(() {
            details.delta.dx > 5
                ? _dragDirectionDX = -1
                : (details.delta.dx < -5 ? _dragDirectionDX = 1 : null);
          });
        },
        onPanEnd: (details) {
          _dragDirectionDX > 0
              ? _nextQuestion()
              : (_dragDirectionDX < 0 ? _previousQuestion() : null);
          _loadQuestion();
          _dragDirectionDX = 0;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Quiz"),
            centerTitle: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                _endQuiz();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        "Question: ${_qIndex + 1}/${widget.settings.questionNumber}",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      AutoSizeText(
                        "Timer: ${_timerCounter ~/ 60}:${(_timerCounter % 60).toInt() < 10 ? "0" + (_timerCounter % 60).toInt().toString() : (_timerCounter % 60).toInt().toString()}",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  QuestionWidget(
                    questionText: _currentQuestion,
                    answers: _currentAnswers,
                    isOver: _isOver,
                    userAnswer: _userAnswers[_qIndex],
                    correctAnswer: widget.questions[_qIndex].correctAnswer,
                    onTapAnswer: !_isOver
                        ? (int index) => _setUserAnswer(index) // ERROR: Throws exception here
                        : (_) =>
                            null,
                    backgroundQuizColor: Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.1),
                    defaultAnswerColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.2),
                    selectedAnswerColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.5),
                    correctAnswerColor:
                        const Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 255, 49).withOpacity(0.5),
                    correctNotSelectedAnswerColor:
                        const Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 94, 32).withOpacity(0.8),
                    wrongAnswerColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          persistentFooterButtons: [
            Row(
              children: [
                // Show previous question
                IconButtonLongPressWidget(
                  lightPalette: MyThemes.lightIconButtonPalette,
                  darkPalette: MyThemes.darkIconButtonPalette,
                  onUpdate: () {
                    _previousQuestion();
                    _loadQuestion();
                  },
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  icon: Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                  iconSize: 35,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                // Show next question
                IconButtonLongPressWidget(
                  lightPalette: MyThemes.lightIconButtonPalette,
                  darkPalette: MyThemes.darkIconButtonPalette,
                  onUpdate: () {
                    _nextQuestion();
                    _loadQuestion();
                  },
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  icon: Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                  iconSize: 35,
                ),
                const Spacer(flex: 5),
                // End/Restart quiz
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    !_isOver ? _endQuiz() : _resetQuiz();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: Text(
                      !_isOver ? "Termina" : "Riavvia",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### QuestionWidget class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:roquiz/model/Answer.dart';

class QuestionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuestionWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.questionNumber,
    required this.questionText,
    this.alignmentQuestion = Alignment.center,
    required this.answers,
    required this.isOver,
    required this.userAnswer,
    required this.correctAnswer,
    required this.onTapAnswer, // funzione vuota di default / null?
    required this.backgroundQuizColor,
    required this.defaultAnswerColor,
    this.selectedAnswerColor = Colors.transparent,
    required this.correctAnswerColor,
    required this.correctNotSelectedAnswerColor,
    this.wrongAnswerColor = Colors.transparent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String questionText;
  final List<String> answers;

  final int? questionNumber; // Index of the current question
  final Alignment alignmentQuestion;
  final bool isOver;
  final Answer userAnswer; // User answer for that question (can be NONE)
  final Answer correctAnswer; // Correct answer
  final Function(int)
      onTapAnswer; // Callback which updates the user selected answer

  final Color backgroundQuizColor;
  final Color defaultAnswerColor;
  final Color selectedAnswerColor;
  final Color correctAnswerColor;
  final Color correctNotSelectedAnswerColor;
  final Color wrongAnswerColor;

  Color _getColor(int index) {
    return !isOver && userAnswer == Answer.values[index]
        ? selectedAnswerColor
        : (!isOver
            ? defaultAnswerColor
            : (correctAnswer == Answer.values[index] &&
                    (userAnswer == Answer.NONE || userAnswer != correctAnswer)
                ? correctAnswerColor
                : (correctAnswer == Answer.values[index]
                    ? correctNotSelectedAnswerColor
                    : (userAnswer == Answer.values[index]
                        ? wrongAnswerColor
                        : defaultAnswerColor))));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: backgroundQuizColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          border: Border.all(color: selectedAnswerColor)),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: alignmentQuestion,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              // Question text
              child: Text(
                  (questionNumber != null ? "Q$questionNumber) " : "") +
                      questionText,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
            ),
          ),
          // ANSWERS
          ...List.generate(
            answers.length,
            (index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
              child: InkWell(
                enableFeedback: true,
                onTap: onTapAnswer(index),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: _getColor(index),
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(children: [
                      // Answer letter
                      Text(Answer.values[index].name + ") ",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Flexible(
                        // Answer text
                        child: Text(answers[index],
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely this `onTap: onTapAnswer(index),` should be `onTap: () => onTapAnswer(index),`

Comment: See Gunter's answer in the linked question.